# How to collapse the height of UILabel to zero in a UITableView programatically

Tags: swift

I have a message / chat app that uses a dynamic table to display a conversation. The screenshot shows the interface in Xcode. There are two status labels, one for each person. My code only displays the status for the last message from the sender and last message from the receiver.

When I do not show a status label I would like to collapse its height to zero so it doesn't leave white space. So far I have tried the following in Swift.

```
let zero: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
cell.status1.sizeThatFits(zero)
cell.status2.sizeThatFits(zero)
```

And:

```
cell.status1.bounds.size.height = 0.0
cell.status2.bounds.size.height = 0.0
```

I have also adjusted number of lines in the interface builder to zero.

May be my approach is incorrect? Can you help?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried UIStackViews, with them you can dynamically add and collapse entire UIViews [with animation].

Comment: constraints may not be allowing you to do that, try change constraints instead

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier status1 and status2 have no height constraint set at present. If I set a height can I change that height programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have IBOutlet for your status label height constraint as -

```
IBOutlet var statusLabelHeightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And then you can set it to zero wherever desired as -

```
statusLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 0
```

Comment: When status has text and height is set to zero the text is not shown so the code is reducing the height to zero however the space it occupied is still there. The cell is using auto row height but it doesn't seem to recalculate. May I need to have the auto height else way so it updates? It's in viewDidLoad() at present.

Comment: After statusLabelHeightConstraint.constant = 0, tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension, and tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

Comment: In place of 44 you can use any value you want. For estimation.

Comment: I had another area constrained incorrectly so after adjusting that and applying the outlet to the constraint it is working as expected.

Comment: Glad I was of help. :-)